# Why am I getting syntax error in nested if..else statement in Django views

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-views

I believe in Python we can do the following:

```
if expression1:
   statement(s)
   if expression2:
      statement(s)
   elif expression3:
      statement(s)
   elif expression4:
      statement(s)
   else:
      statement(s)
else:
   statement(s)
```

I am trying to do something like this in Django views:

```
if qs1.count() > 100:
    # do something
elif qs1.count() - qs2(count) < 12:
    # do something else
elif qs3.count() > qs2.count():
    if qs1.count() == qs3.count():        # Error here <<
         # do whatever
else:
    # forget it
```

I am getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at the code line shown.

**What am I doing wrong? How do I improve the statement flow so as not to encounter an error.**

Comment: is there a reason you didn't include all the information you were given about the error?

Comment: It might be useful to show the details. The above program is syntactically correct, but likely the `# do something`s, etc. generate a syntax problem (like not closing a bracket, etc.).

Comment: The exact error msg is `  File "/Users/********/views.py", line 3854
    if (qs_bool_false.count() == qs_all_items.count():` **The error points to this line...**

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem- The code lines shown is precisely what I have in my views. The next line is where I am trying to **print** some variable to do a kind of debugging. The error is occurring only when I have the `if` after the `elif` statement. I am editing my post pls.

Comment: @12379095: it does not :) it shows a leading bracket that you did not close :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off your syntax error

```
if (qs_bool_false.count() == qs_all_items.count():
```

You can fix it like this

```
if qs_bool_false.count() == qs_all_items.count():
```